# ORA-64219: invalid LOB locator encountered

Tags: c#, oracle, devart

We migrated from oracle c12 to c19. And now we have simple test case that fails:

```
//arrange
string data = new string('x', 5000);
var connection = tm.GetConnection();

var createTableCmd = connection.CreateCommand(false);
createTableCmd.Text = "CREATE TABLE xx_temp (id NUMBER, text_long NCLOB, text_short NVARCHAR2(2000))";
createTableCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

//act
var insertCmd = connection.CreateCommand(false);
insertCmd.Text = "INSERT INTO XX_TEMP (text_long) VALUES (@p1)";
var param = new OracleParameter("@p1", OracleDbType.NClob, data.Length, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input);
param.Value = data;
insertCmd.Parameters.Add(param);
var insertResult = insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The last line fails with the error: `ORA-64219: invalid LOB locator encountered`

We're using `Devart.Data.Oracle` component. And I have no idea what is wrong.

What is interesting is that when I'm trying to connect to DB from powershell using `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll`, I have no problems using similar code.

Comment: I know this isn't quite what you're asking, but is there a reason not to use Oracle's own ODP.NET?

Comment: @WSC the problem that we already have a big project that uses devart

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade to dotConnect for Oracle v9.11.980. The following code works with v9.11.980 and Oracle 19c:

```
//arrange
string data = new string('x', 5000);
var connection = new OracleConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = @"User Id=****;Password=****;Server=YOUR_HOST/YOUR_SID;Direct=true;";
connection.Open();

var createTableCmd = connection.CreateCommand();
//createTableCmd.CommandText = "DROP TABLE xx_temp";
//createTableCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
createTableCmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE xx_temp (id NUMBER, text_long NCLOB, text_short NVARCHAR2(2000))";
createTableCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

//act
var insertCmd = connection.CreateCommand();
insertCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO XX_TEMP (text_long) VALUES (:p1)";
var param = new OracleParameter("p1", OracleDbType.NClob, data.Length, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input);
param.Value = data;
insertCmd.Parameters.Add(param);
var insertResult = insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```